# Classic ASP Import Remote XML file into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, asp-classic, xml-parsing

First off I would like to say that I think that my question may be time consuming for people to solve it in a complete sense so I understand that it is totally possible that the complete answer is asking for just way too much, so anything to help me better understand, like: reading material, examples, links, and/or advice would be great and I do very much appreciate any and every comment I receive, good or bad it just makes me and this place alot better, finally, I would like to thank you all so much for everything that you do here, this is truly a place that was build by smart people, and people that care.

MY QUESTION

(using Classic ASP and SQL Server)

I know that it is possible to read a remote XML file and then insert it into a SQL Server database table. I found one example that does that it uses Classic ASP and MS Access but that can be changed to SQL Server with minimal coding the URL is: http://forums.aspfree.com/code-bank-54/classic-asp-import-remote-xml-file-into-database-152966.html

But the problem is that I cannot get it to work on my remote XML file, I tried to edit the classic asp code (found in the link above) for days and days and I just cannot get it to work the way I would like.

So I want to start from the beginning,

The XML file in question is located on: http://www.iftach.org/taxmatrix/charts/2Q2012.xml

I seen a couple of examples on how you can export the entire xml file into the SQL Server database (like do a BULK insert, see URL: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316005) and also on how to extract some info. from the XML but my request is kind of odd since I want to check for the `Country` first and then get that `Counties Rate` only and not the other one, I want to do this for the entire xml file.

For example the xml file is something like this:
(or you can view the full xml file by clicking on the URL above)

```
<FILE>
<QUARTER>2Q2012</QUARTER>
<RECORD>
<JURISDICTION ID="#15">AB</JURISDICTION>
<COUNTRY>CAN</COUNTRY>
......
......
<RATE RATECHANGE="0" COUNTRY="US">0.3366</RATE>
<RATE RATECHANGE="0" COUNTRY="CAN">0.0900</RATE>
......
......
......
</RECORD>

<RECORD>
<JURISDICTION ID="#15">FL</JURISDICTION>
<COUNTRY>U.S.</COUNTRY>
......
......
<RATE RATECHANGE="0" COUNTRY="US">1.5700</RATE>
<RATE RATECHANGE="0" COUNTRY="CAN">1.3210</RATE>
......
......
......
</RECORD>
</FILE>
```

and so on....

Now I would like to insert that info into the SQL Server table called `FFTR` and name the column specific for each `JURISDICTION`

Like for example the above would be:

```
Field Name 1 --> "JURISDICTION_AB_CAN"
Field Name 2 --> "JURISDICTION_FL_US"
and so on...
```

NOTE:
The prefix `JURISDICTION_` will always be the same only the two letters will change and the `CAN` can become `US`.

Another thing is if the COUNTRY is "CAN" then I would like to use the CAN Rate and if it's U.S. I would like to use the US Rate and insert that info. into the database with the Field named "RATE". (The Rate will always be 4 decimal places) the Rate I want is only under: `<FUEL_TYPE>Special Diesel</FUEL_TYPE>` I don't need the other Rates.

And the last thing I would like to do is to have the `<QUARTER>2Q2012</QUARTER>` inserted into a Field named "Quarter"

So the final SQL Server database would look like this (using the 2 records as an example above)

```
Field Name: JURISDICTION_AB_CAN
Rate: 0.0900
Quarter: 2Q2012

Field Name: JURISDICTION_FL_US
Rate: 1.5700
Quarter: 2Q2012
```

So what I tried to do is this (see code below) and I got it to show each line but it doesn't even come close to a solution:

```
<% 
   Option Explicit 
   Response.Buffer = True 
   Dim xml 
   Set xml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") 
   xml.async = False 
   xml.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True 
   xml.Load ("http://www.iftach.org/TaxMatrix/charts/2Q2012.xml") 
   Dim paragraph1,paragraph2,paragraph3,paragraph4,paragraph5,paragraph6

   paragraph1 = xml.documentElement.childNodes(1).text
   paragraph2 = xml.documentElement.childNodes(2).text
   paragraph3 = xml.documentElement.childNodes(3).text
   paragraph4 = xml.documentElement.childNodes(4).text
   paragraph5 = xml.documentElement.childNodes(5).text
   paragraph6 = xml.documentElement.childNodes(6).text

   Set xml = Nothing 
%> 
<html> 
   <head> 
   <title></title> 
   </head> 
   <body> 
   <p align="center"><% = paragraph1 %></p>
   <p align="center"><% = paragraph2 %></p>
   <p align="center"><% = paragraph3 %></p>
   <p align="center"><% = paragraph4 %></p>
   <p align="center"><% = paragraph5 %></p>
   <p align="center"><% = paragraph6 %></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I even think that adding it to a ADODB Recordset would be great and then I would insert it into SQL Server one by one or just loop it all in there, but it only shows me the columns I need the rows in there also. See code below:

```
<%
 Dim objRS
 Set objRS =  Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  objRS.ActiveConnection = "Provider=MSDAOSP; Data Source=MSXML2.DSOControl.3.0;"
  objRS.Open(Server.MapPath("2Q2012.xml"))


Response.Write(objRS.Fields(2) & "<br>") ' <-- Returns the Quarter only, that I need for the Quarter Field in the DB

'Response.Write(objRS.Fields(6) & "<br>") ' <-- Returns the entire xml page

Do While Not objRS.EOF

 objRS.MoveNext
 Loop


%>

<table border="1" width="100%">
 <%
 dim fld
 Response.Write("<tr>")
 For Each fld in objRS.Fields
 If fld.Name <> "$Text" Then
 Response.Write("<td>" & fld.Name & "</td>")
 End If
 Next
 Response.Write("</tr>")
 Do While Not objRS.EOF
 Response.Write("<tr>")
 For Each fld in objRS.Fields
 If fld.Name <> "$Text" Then
 Response.Write("<td>" & fld.Value & "</td>")
 End If
 Next
 Response.Write("</tr>")
 objRS.MoveNext
 Loop
 %>
 </table>
```

Again, Thank you so much for any advice, links, or any help at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally!!! I made it work, if anyone needs the solution it is below:
Using the code I posted in the question I added the following code:

Note: I know that this is not the best way to do it since I'm not going after the TAGS/IDs/Names but the xml file will always stay formated the same so I just Looped, Cut out what I needed, and Inserted/Updated into the DB.

```
    <%
    ' LOOP ALL OF THE FIELDS ONE BY ONE
     For x = 0 to xml.documentelement.childnodes.length - 1
     set XMLobjchildnodes = xml.documentelement.childnodes
     strXMLtxt=xml.documentElement.childNodes(x).text & "<br>"


    ' SETUP THE UPDATE FIELDS FOR SQL
     dim strTest
     strTest="objSQL(""IMP_STATE_" & Mid(strXMLtxt,1,2) & """)=" & Mid(strXMLtxt,46,7)

    ' SKIP THE Fi and 2Q because they are not States/Prov.
    if strTest="objSQL(""IMP_STATE_Fi"")=" OR strTest="objSQL(""IMP_STATE_2Q"")=" then
    else

    ' ALSO SKIP hi and U and CN because they also are not States/Prov.
    if InStr(strTest,"STATE_ht")>0 OR InStr(strTest,"STATE_U.")>0 OR InStr(strTest,"STATE_CN")>0 then
    else

    ' ADD YOUR SQL CONNECTION INFO. HERE AND THEN INSERT/UPDATE THE SQL DB


    end if
Next
    %>
```

Note: By making small changes you can set it to Insert the data into SQL and/or update, should this be a problem for anyone please let me know I will be more then happy to help.

To all that have tried to solve my problem/question, Thank you so much for all of your hard work and effort.

Comment: For the benefit of others that might copy the techinique here: don't.  Sucking in XML from a foreign source and concatinating it into SQL code that is then executed is risky thing to do.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones I agree that this is a super risky thing to do so always use parameterized query. For more info. on parameterized query and stored procedures you can read up on it here http://palizine.plynt.com/issues/2006Jun/injection-stored-procedures/ or even better just search stackoverflow for Parameterized query

Answer (score 0):

have a look here: [msxml DOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754523%28v=vs.85%29)

you should use the msxml object to read the xml. then you can query the elements of the xml by using the api.

example code for loading the xml:

```
<%
dim xml : set xml = server.createobject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
dim xmlString : xmlString = getXMLHTTPResponse("http://www.iftach.org/TaxMatrix/charts/2Q2012.xml")
xml.loadxml(xmlString)

function getXMLHTTPResponse(url)
    dim tout, xmlhttp

    set xmlhttp = server.createObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    with xmlhttp
        .setTimeouts 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000
        .open "GET", url, false
        .send()
        if .responseXML.xml = "" then
            getXMLHTTPResponse = .responseText
        else
            getXMLHTTPResponse = .responseXML.xml
        end if
    end with
end function
%>
```